# SQL Server : select unique entries using distinct keyword but it's returning all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
select distinct  
    TM.Tranaction_Slno, TM.Created_On,
    convert(varchar(10), TM.Created_On, 120) as CreatedOn,  
    TT.Read_Time,
    convert(varchar(10), TT.Read_Time, 120) as ReadTime,        
    1 as 'Trailer Count', TMM.Trailer_RegNo, TT.Location,        
    (TD.Container_Number) Container_Number, CFM.CFS_Name,        
    convert(varchar(5), DateDiff(s, TM.Created_On, TT.Read_Time) / 3600) + ':' +        
       convert(varchar(5), DateDiff(s, TM.Created_On,  TT.Read_Time) % 3600 / 60) + ':'+        
       convert(varchar(5), (DateDiff(s, TM.Created_On, TT.Read_Time) % 60))  TimeDiff,        
    convert(varchar(5), DateDiff(hour, TM.Created_On, Read_Time)) [Time]
from 
    Transaction_Master TM         
inner join 
    Transaction_Data TD on TD.Tranaction_Slno = TM.Tranaction_Slno        
left join 
    Transaction_Track TT on TT.Transaction_Slno = TM.Tranaction_Slno 
inner join 
    CFSMaster CFM on TM.CFS_ID = CFM.CFS_Id        
inner join 
    TrailerMaster TMM on TM.Trailer_ID= TMM.Trailer_ID        
where 
    TM.Created_On between '2019-02-27 00:00:00' and '2019-02-27 23:59:59' 
    and TM.Tranaction_Slno = 1770575
```

I am selecting the entries which would return only distinct but it's not returning. The screenshot is shown below:

[image]

Comment: You Location, Container_number, Time Diff, Time are unique attributes.

Comment: Location,Container_number,Time Diff, Time are repeating. the result i need is it should return only 3 rows @Avi

Comment: You can use row_number and then partition by either location, container number or time diff and then select row_number = 1 to get 3 rows

Comment: @Avi can you please help with me example query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may work to get 3 rows, please note that I used only location and Transaction in partition.

```
select * from (
select    TM.Tranaction_Slno, TM.Created_On,convert(varchar(10),TM.Created_On,120) as CreatedOn,  
TT.Read_Time,convert(varchar(10),TT.Read_Time,120) as ReadTime,        
1 as 'Trailer Count' ,TMM.Trailer_RegNo,TT.Location,        
(TD.Container_Number) Container_Number ,CFM.CFS_Name, row_number() over (partition by TM.Tranaction_Slno,TT.Location order by TM.Created_On desc) rownum           
convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, TM.Created_On, TT.Read_Time)/3600)+':'+        
convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, TM.Created_On, TT.Read_Time)%3600/60)+':'+        
convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, TM.Created_On, TT.Read_Time)%60))  TimeDiff,        
convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(hour, TM.Created_On, Read_Time))  [Time]
from Transaction_Master TM         
inner join Transaction_Data TD on TD.Tranaction_Slno = TM.Tranaction_Slno        
left join Transaction_Track TT on TT.Transaction_Slno = TM.Tranaction_Slno 
inner join CFSMaster CFM on TM.CFS_ID = CFM.CFS_Id        
inner join TrailerMaster TMM on TM.Trailer_ID= TMM.Trailer_ID        
where TM.Created_On between '2019-02-27 00:00:00' and '2019-02-27 23:59:59' 
and TM.Tranaction_Slno=1770575 ) test 
where test.rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove from the list of columns Container_Number. 
You'll get only 3 rows.

If you need the Container_Number info, you may consider using a group by instead.

Comment: what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @NiranjanS simple, just take the Container_Number out of your query and you'll get three rows only. The reason why you get 6 rows is because your Container_Number IS DISTINCT for two rows that look identical, but ain't because of your DISTINCT Container_Number. The distinct will apply for a combination of all columns, not just one column, but over the of all. So, because Container_Number is different, distinct, the row is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Here, only to illustrate what I'm saying in comment.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5CUuAwng7ZAyVinSo36Q5f/0